# How to merge forEach and sorting method together?

Tags: javascript, html, sorting

The problem I'm having with the code is that I can't get the array to appear and sorted onclick rather than having it appear and be sorted when I click the button.

Another thing I'm having trouble with is getting the forEach method to merge in with the sorting method. It just returns "undefinedbr".

```js
var hobbies = ["Conga Dancing", "Reading", "Ethical Hacking", "Snowboarding", "Social Expeirementing", "Playing Games"];
hobbies.forEach(myloopfunc);

function myloopfunc(item, index) {
  hobbies.sort();
  document.getElementById("sorting").innerHTML = hobbies;
  document.getElementById("sorting").innerHTML = index+" "+ item+ "<br>";
}
```

```html
<button onclick="myloopfunc()">Button</button>

<p id="sorting"></p>
```

EDITED version

The new code still doesn't work even though it's aligned with the code in this https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/tryit.asp?filename=tryjsref_foreach. I'm not understanding why it still wouldn't work even though the code in the website does.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Always check the browser console for errors before asking why things aren't working as expected. `Uncaught ReferenceError: forEach is not defined @ JS line 2` Did you mean to invoke `Array.prototype.forEach`?

Comment: I'm new to Javascript, so I'm not familiar with that concept, I'll research it on my own time, but apart from that. Take away the forEach method, the line doesn't up when you automatically get into the browser.

Comment: Before merging `forEach` and `sort`, it would be good to first figure out the right syntax for `forEach` alone

Comment: @CertainPerformance According to this [link](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/tryit.asp?filename=tryjsref_foreach) , my syntax is correct but I'm not able to fathom the difference between theirs and mines. The new error I receive now is ```Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'innerHTML' of null```

Comment: Your link is using `fruits.forEach`, but you're calling `forEach` as if it was a stanadalone function, which it isn't

Comment: I'm running my own edited version of this where I solely focus on the syntax of forEach() method and before I responded to you, I ran ```var hobbies=["Conga Dancing", "Reading", "Ethical Hacking", "Snowboarding", "Social Expeirementing", "Playing Games"];
hobbies.forEach(myloopfunc);

function myloopfunc(item,index) {
  document.getElementById("sorting").innerHTML+=index+" "+item +"<br>";
}``` however, it still doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

I have changed your code and am not sure whether my code is doing what you want.

As far as I know that you want a sorted array when the button is clicked, but  in your html code, you call `myloopfunc()` which only performs the task of assigning index to each item and output to the browser. There is no sorting happening here.

In order to achieve the task, you need another function that combines the sort and assigning task for your array.

```js
var hobbies=["Conga Dancing", "Reading", "Ethical Hacking", "Snowboarding", "Social Expeirementing", "Playing Games"]; 

function myloopfunc(item,index) { document.getElementById("sorting").innerHTML+=index+" "+item +"<br>"; }
function callAnotherFunction() {
  hobbies.sort().forEach(myloopfunc); 
}
```

```html
<button onclick=callAnotherFunction()>Button</button>

<p id="sorting"></p>
```